# Doctrine 2 delete with query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two Entities with relation OneToMany, `Project` and `Services`. Now i want to remove all the services by project_id.

First attempt:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete('Services','s');
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('s.project_id', ':id'));
$qb->setParameter(':id',$project->getId());
```

This attempt fails with the Exception `Entity Service does not have property project_id`. And it's true, that property does not exists, it's only in database table as foreign key.

Second attempt:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete('Services','s')->innerJoin('s.project','p');
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('p.id', ':id'));
$qb->setParameter(':id',$project->getId());
```

This one generetate a non valid DQL query too.

Any ideas and examples will be welcome.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You're working with DQL, not SQL, so don't reference the IDs in your condition, reference the object instead.

So your first example would be altered to:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete('Services', 's');
$qb->where('s.project = :project');
$qb->setParameter('project', $project);
```

Comment: Third line can be rewritten as follows: $qb->where('s.project = :project');

Comment: To execute the query, add: ->getQuery()->execute();

Comment: @roelleor thanks, this should be added to the main answer, I knew something probably needed to be added but i didn't know what

Answer (score 3):

If you really can't get project object and you have to handle only with id you can use this.

Citation from doctrine documentation:
There are two possibilities for bulk deletes with Doctrine. You can either issue a single DQL DELETE query or you can iterate over results removing them one at a time. (Below I paste only first solution)

DQL Query
The by far most efficient way for bulk deletes is to use a DQL DELETE query.

Example that worked in my project

```
$q = $em->createQuery('delete from AcmeMyTestBundle:TemplateBlock tb where tb.template = '.intval($templateId));
$numDeleted = $q->execute();
```

In entity TemplateBlock I have property called template which is mapped to template_id in db.

But I agree that highly preferred way of doing it is using objects.

Comment: Don't do this at home, please be aware of SQL injections!

Comment: Note that DQL queries don't trigger Doctrine Lifecycle events

Comment: the recommended way would be `$service = $entityManager()->getReference(Services::class, 1);` This is a dummy object only used for reference in DQL Queries.