# Delete collection of records from database using symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I want to select set of records from a table(process) process it and delete it.

I am running the following query to select. How to I delete all the selected records of group by statement in symfony2.

```
createQuery('SELECT process FROM WebBundle:process process
                       GROUP BY process.tag')->getResult();
```

How do I delete all the rows selected using symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query builder to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555495/1348344).

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete('Processes', 'p');
```

For more info, just [check documentation - DQL - Delete queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#delete-queries).