# Cannot Delete User - QueryException: DELETE WHERE u.id = :id

Tags: php, symfony

I am working in Symfony - When I am performing an action to delete a user I am receiving the following error messages:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'WHERE u.id =': Error: Class 'WHERE' is not defined.
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
1 linked Exception:

QueryException » 

1/2 QueryException: DELETE WHERE u.id = :id
2/2 QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'WHERE u.id =': Error: Class 'WHERE' is not defined.
```

**Admin Controller**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/admin/user/delete/{id}", name="admin_user_delete")
 * @Template
 */
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $dispatcher = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');

    $this->get('users')->delete($id);

    // create the user event and dispatch it
    $event = new UserEvent($id);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(UserEvents::USER_DELETED, $event);

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice-success', 'User deleted successfully.');

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_user_list'));
}
```

**User.php Service**

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->repository->delete($id);
}
```

**User Repository**

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->delete()
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('u.id', ':id'))
        ->setParameter(':id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: You don't use the `:` character in the `setParameter()` call. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: fixed, although same errors remain

Comment: Are you trying to delete in a Controller or an Entity file?

Comment: The : is actually irrelevant.  DQL works with objects not ids.  Take a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555042/doctrine-2-delete-with-query-builder You will need to create a reference to the user object.  I think $em->remove($user) followed by a flush would be a cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad - this looks to be right direction. This is a pretty new environment for me - any chance you could guide me in writing it out? I've been playing around but am flunking out.

Answer (score 1):

Method to delete a user with the query builder

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    return $qb->delete('Bundle:User', 'u')
        ->where('u.id = :id'))
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

How to delete a user using the built in ORM

```
public function delete($id) {
    // get access to the entity manager
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    // get the user from the repository by id
    // previous version, slightly slower as it executes a query
    // $user = $em->getRepository('Bundle:User')->find($id);

    // Cerads method I just found out about myself, even better version!
    // this doesn't execute a query but gets a reference to the user object 
    // and sets the id
    $user = $em->getReference('Bundle:User', $id);

    // use built in methods to delete the user
    $em->remove($user);
    // update the database with the change
    $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: In your second approach, replace find with getReference($id).  No need to load the entire user object just to delete it.  And have you actually tried the first approach?  Not positive you have it quite right.  Pretty sure you will need something like Bundle:User.

Comment: You're right on both counts, I just put user not thinking the reading user might not know to access it through the bundle. I actually didn't know about the getReference() call though, that's incredibly useful. Thank you!

Comment: @JacobW when using your Method, I am receiving

`Unknown Entity namespace alias 'Bundle'.
500 Internal Server Error - ORMException `

Comment: @RKlina - I think you at the point where you know just enough to get in trouble.  Pause for a bit and go back read through the Doctrine chapter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html Things should start to make a bit more sense the second time round.

Comment: Indeed. Will revisit and jump back in - very much appreciate the input!

Comment: Yeah, like Cerad said. You need the name of the bundle the entity resides in. Often it'll be SiteBundle or whatever you named the folders in src/.

ex. If you have src/Brand/Site/CompanyBundle then the default bundle reference is BrandSiteCompanyBundle and the entity Reference would be similar to User so the reference above would be BrandSiteCompanyBundle:User.

Comment: Got it going last night, popped in today to say thanks guys! Yup, got it together after reviewing the docs. Had a foreign key issue after that, but was able to resolve. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 0):

As Jared Farrish said above, you don't need the colon in the `setParameter` call.

Should be:

`->setParameter('id', $id)`

Comment: Thank you - reading over posted docs.doctrine... 

Same errors do remain after fix.

Comment: As I said in a comment, not an answer. `;)`