# How to delete from database with queryBuilder?

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to delete some data and return the number of the deleting. 
This is my code :

```
public function deleteMyData() : ?int
{
    $qb = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder()
        ->delete('myTable')
        ->where('pays ="us"')
    ;
    return $qb->execute()->rowCount();
}
```

I already tested other things like :

```
->delete()
->from('myTable')
->where('pays ="fr"')
```

When I run my code I've got this error :

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>
> Call to a member function rowCount() on integer

I dumped `$qb->execute()->rowCount()` and it return "0".

Thanks for your help !

PS : I think that the problem isn't the query because :

> Error An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM theQueryTest WHERE pays ="us"':

The SQL is great

PS 2 : I can't use `->getQuery()`

[image]

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555042/doctrine-2-delete-with-query-builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

In my case, I have to use `$this->connection` HOWEVER I don't have to use `$qb->execute()`

I read the doc and I found this in Connection.php (->delete(...)) :

> - @return integer The number of affected rows.

So I have to use directly `$this->connection->delete(...)`

```
public function deleteMyData() : ?int
{
    $qb = $this->connection
        ->delete('myTable', ['pays' => '"us"'])
    ;
    return $qb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code returns an integer

```
return $qb->execute();
```

If you want to count row affected try this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
//query
$count = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Comment: With $this->connection->createQueryBuilder() there isn't ->getQuery(), I already tried.

Only : ->getQueryPart() or ->getQueryParts()

Comment: Connection is : use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

So I don't have getEntityManager()
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes I'm in a repository, but I use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection

Comment: because you can use directly: $this->createQueryBuilder() without connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158148/discussion-between-n-jourdan-and-alessandro-minoccheri).